# awk for many compressed files

Tags: shell, awk, gzip

The following command calculates the GC content for *each* fasta [fastq files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) 
identified with the find command. Briefly a fastq is a file which for a large number of datapoints have 4 lines of information and where the second line I'm interested in only contains (ATGC). For testing (identical) example files can be found [here](http://people.binf.ku.dk/rtl144/random/)).

```
find . -iname '*.fastq' -exec awk '(NR%4==2) {N1+=length($0);gsub(/[AT]/,"");N2+=length($0);}END{print N2/N1;}' "{}" \;
```

How can I modify/rewrite it into a one-liner that works on gziped fastq files? I need the regex option currently used with find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` '-exec' can be used to invoke (and pass arguments) to a single program. The challenge here is that two commands (cat|awk) need to be combined with a pipe. Two possible path: construct a shell command OR use the more flexible xargs.

```
# Using the 'shell -c' command
find . -iname '*.fastq.gz' -exec sh -c "zcat {} | awk '(NR%4==2) \
{N1+=length(\$0);gsub(/[AT]/,\"\");N2+=length(\$0);}END{print N2/N1;}'" \;

# OR, using process substitution
find . -iname '*.fastq.gz' -exec bash -c "awk '(NR%4==2) \
{N1+=length(\$0);gsub(/[AT]/,\"\");N2+=length(\$0);}END{print N2/N1;}' <(zcat {})" \;
```

See many references to find/xargs in stack overflow

Comment: It seems the command is unfinished...? I just get a newline with a ">" when I try it

Comment: @KristofferVitting-Seerup, added terminating quotes, bad copy/paste

Comment: The first pipeline now gives 1 for both test files (supposed to be 0.58) and the second pipeline gives the following error ```sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected``` for each file

Comment: @KristofferVitting-Seerup Thanks for checking. I should have used the real files. I've fixed the quoting of $0 (\$), and force bash into the second option (for process substitution support). Both are running, and produce 0.606667 for me

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, you have many large files, I would suggest processing them in parallel. If the issue is that you are having problems quoting your `awk`, I would suggest putting your script in a separate file, called, say `script.awk` like this:

```
(NR%4==2) {N1+=length($0);gsub(/[AT]/,"");N2+=length($0);}END{print N2/N1;}
```

Now you can simply process them all in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
find . -iname \*fastq.gz -print0 | parallel -0 gzcat {} \| awk -f ./script.awk
```

Comment: Just had to change it to ```'*fastq.gz'```(and use zcat) then it worked nicely

Comment: Dash-o gets the accepted answer due to the "one-liner" part of my request. Thanks for the awk script trick - will be handy in the future.